# Circle around the perimeter of the display. Processing

Tags: processing

Cant figure this out - beginner

So i'm trying to get the circle to track around the perimeter of the display. So far Ive managed to move the circle from the bottom left to top left but cant get it to go the opposite way....wrecking my head. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```java
int circleX = 0;
int circleY = 500;


void setup() {
size(500,500);
noStroke();
}

void draw() {
circleX = circleX + 4;

if(circleX>421) {
circleX = 420;
circleY = circleY -4;
} 

if (circleY<80) {
circleY=80;
circleX = circleX -4;
}

background(#17202A);
fill(#FF00E0);
ellipse(circleX,circleY, 60,60); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to do something like track which direction the circle is moving. You could do this using a series of `boolean` variables:

```
boolean goingUp = false;
boolean goingRight = true;
boolean goingDown = false;
boolean goingLeft = false;
```

Then in your `draw()` function, you'd move your `circleX` and `circleY` variables based on these `boolean` variables. You'd also use **collision detection** to detect when the circle hit a certain corner, and update the variables accordingly.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation) is a tutorial on animation in Processing, and [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) is a tutorial on collision detection in Processing.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I'll give it a shot and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Managed a much simpler way....I still want to do more with it (e.g stop at each corner and change colour) but this is a start.

Comment: int circleX = 80;
int circleY = 420;
int m = millis();


void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  noStroke();
}

void draw() {
  
  background(#17202A);
  fill(#FF00E0);
  ellipse(circleX, circleY, 60, 60);
  
  if (circleY == 420) {
    circleX = circleX +4;

  }
  if (circleX == 420) {
    circleY = circleY -4;
  }
  if (circleY == 80) {
  circleX = circleX -4;

  }
  if (circleX == 80) {
  circleY = circleY +4;
  
  }
}